# parameter_descriptions and parameter_updates topics

Tags: ros, hector-quadrotor, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear friends,

I experiment with hector quadrotor simulation in Hydro. Most of the topics like the one for sonar of the altimeter includes additional topics like /sonar_height/parameter_descriptions and /sonar_height/paramater_updates.

What is the use of these topics in every component?

It can be used in order to change the on fly the parameters of the virtual device or something else?

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213290/parameter_descriptions-and-parameter_updates-topics/) by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These topics are used by the dynamic_reconfigure framework to change some device parameters while the node is running.

See: [the dynamic_reconfigure wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) for more details

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on 2015-07-09**:
That's make sense, so I can use them as normal topics when I want to update the device's config when the node is already running - thanks